Question on borrowing in Rust with closures
I am trying a sample program in Rust to understand closures as follows. But I get in error for the line "After defining closure" below.
    let mut list = vec![1, 2, 3];
    println!("Before defining closure: {list:?}");
    
    let mut borrows_mutably = || list.push(7);
    println!("After defining closure: {list:?}");
    
    borrows_mutably();
    println!("After calling closure: {list:?}");

The error is as follows.
|
61 |     let mut borrows_mutably = || list.push(7);
|                               -- ---- first borrow occurs due to use of `list` in closure
|                               |
|                               mutable borrow occurs here
62 |     println!("After defining closure: {list:?}");
|                                       ^^^^^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
63 |
64 |     borrows_mutably();
|     --------------- mutable borrow later used here

My question is why does the first borrow happen when I defined the closure. Shouldn't it be after I call the closure?

Welcome to SO! :) That callback is not just a definition. A closure object containing the borrowed reference gets created right when the execution hits that line of code. That's why the borrow needs to happen at exactly that time, not when you call it.

A closure is a value that can be called like a function. The value you're creating here contains an &mut Vec<_>. If you don't want the closure itself to borrow, give it list via a parameter instead.

I figured out the following explanation from the Rust book. Looks like the definition of closure itself is doing the borrow, though I can't understand the rationale behind it.

Between the closure definition and the closure call, an immutable
borrow to print isn’t allowed because no other borrows are allowed
when there’s a mutable borrow.

